# How to design a Windows Store App that is document-centric?

Tags: windows-8, windows-store-apps

I want to create a document-centric Windows Store app, and am having problems because all of the VS templates are single page, grid or hub layouts of static data.

What if a single file contained data that needed editing on a number of pages?  Fore example, a spreadsheet app, with one main page (MainPage) for editing the spreadsheet, another page for creating a report (ReportPage).

The user opens a spreadsheet file on the main page, the data is loaded into data-models, a model is created from the data-models, controls are created and bound to the model.  The user makes some changes, and then, without saving anything moves to the report page.

That report page needs access to the same model that the MainPage uses.  So should I pass the model over to the ReportPage as a navigational parameter?  Or should I hold the model in the App class instead of the MainPage?

What if the MainPage takes a lot of resources to create?  When the user returns to the MainPage, all those controls will have to be created and bound again.

How does the Windows Store App architecture support document-centric apps?  Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a couple of days research, the answer is: Do the whole app on one page.  Do not switch pages.  Have a main page where all of the views are declared in the xaml but with visibility bound to boolean fields in the MainPage view model.  Small forms can be popped up as windows.

This obviously requires more memory than switching between pages, but backed by a single view-model, and this view-model stays loaded for the duration of app's lifetime.